# Search components based on fields

Tags: search

How do I search a Component based on text in the hyperlink field?

I need to update the hyperlink from certain components among thousands of components. Problem is that I don't know how to search these components by using Tridion search, tried searching the text from hyperlink but no results were found.

If anyone can provide the answer, it will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give an example of what the hyperlink  you are searching for looks like and what search terms have you tried? I think the challenge is finding the correct search term, since CM content is indexed by words, and a link doesn't contain spaces, so is considered a single word with special characters (provided that it is actually indexed)

Comment: You might want to have a look here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-can-i-do-a-cme-search-for-arbitrary-strings-in-template-code/3404#3404

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for a hyperlink that appears within a field you've defined in your component schema, you ought to be able to use the advanced search options to limit your search to specific fields within components.

[image: Advanced search in Tridion]

To open the advanced search field, tick the little triangle next to the normal search bar.
Then choose **"Based on Schema"**, and select your particular Schema.
Then choose the name of the Schema field which contains hyperlink.

Now you should be able to search for a relevant text string, like a meaningful part of a hyperlink, in that Search Term field.